# I can't deploy Firebase functions because I don't have "Service Account User" Role

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-identity

I'm trying to deploy Firebase Functions like so:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Missing permissions required for functions deploy. You must have permission iam.serviceAccounts.ActAs on service account xyz@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.
> To address this error, ask a project Owner to assign your account the "Service Account User" role from this URL:
> https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?xyz

I've already given myself Service Account User permission by going to

Identity -> Service Accounts -> xyz@appspot.gserviceaccount.com -> Permissions -> + Grant Access

I've added my email and service account linked in `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. I'm still getting the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have Owner or at least Editor role in your *firebase* console and not on GCP ? Check if you have role as owner or editor and then try

Comment: I am facing same issue on my Bitrise CI/CD pipeline. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you verify that you are logged with the correct account and that you are linked to the project?
You can double check by creating a new project and then in cli

```
$ firebase logout
$ firebase login
$ firebase init
```

Comment: Does not work for CD